# How to show hashtags separately in uitextfield in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, hashtag

I want design a textfield in which if user enter some text as hashtag then it should be visible separately with diffrent color & a cross button like in other apps.I have searched a lot but i am not able to find out the solution.Please provide the solution regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you search on GitHub for a token field?

Comment: https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField

Comment: is there other way without using third party lib?

Comment: "Like in other app", any example ? Screenshot example (we might not know/use the app you're talking about). You can always search for Hashtags and show them elsewhere, playing with NSAttributedString or another component of your own.

Comment: as in facebook & twitter app